# What is the meaning of 'the food chain'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

The OED confirms my long-held suspicion that the original use of the term 'food chain' is becoming supplanted by an altogether different meaning.

The term 'food chain' was used extensively in the 1950s when scientists first became aware of the dangers associated with the pesticide DDT. The poison built up in the food chain until it reached humans at the top.

**The OED says**: **under Ia**. *A series of organisms, each of which is dependent on the next for food, esp. by direct consumption or predation.
1920   Sci. Monthly Oct. 295   Each such fish has its ‘food-chain’..leading back from the food of man to invertebrates upon which it preys and then to the food of these.
1980   R. Mabey Common Ground i. 32   The accumulation in the birds of toxic agricultural pesticides, passed down the food chain from dressed grain to seed-eater to bird-of-prey.
2005   New Scientist 12 Nov. 44/1   Food chains here [sc. at deep ocean vents] are based not on photosynthesis, but on a process called chemosynthesis.*

Nowadays the term 'food chain' seems most frequently to be used to describe the various events  necessary to bring food to the table, from agriculture, to distribution, to packaging, to preparation and sale.

**OED 2.**

*The system or sequence of events by which food comes to be consumed by human beings.
1951   Ecology 32 351   The base of the human food chain is the production of plant organic matter.
1993   Independent 23 Oct. (Weekend section) 35/1   An elongated food chain involving numerous intermediate links—processors, packers, hauliers.
2003   Observer 5 Jan. i. 8/1   Defences against a bioterrorist attack involving animal diseases such as foot and mouth are to be stepped up to prevent rogue groups targeting Britain's food chain.*

We have thus arrived at a confusing situation. How, in the view of subscribers to this site, should 'food chain' be used. If both are to continue how do we make it clear to readers and listeners which one we are talking about?

Comment: In their entry for ***street boy***, OED also record the increasingly-common "facetious" usage: 2005 V. Swarup Q&A   *Street boys like me come **at the bottom of the food chain**. Above us are the petty criminals, like pickpockets.* Presumably readers and listeners will do what they've always done - figure out the intended sense ***by context***.

Comment: Yes, there are numerous metaphorical uses of 'food chain', some of which are in the OED. It could be that meaning 2 started out as metaphor, but many people, I feel sure, now accept it as the principal meaning.

Comment: With expressions like this I'm not sure it means much to say there's a "principal" meaning. There are just *several* meanings, and in practice it would normally be really obvious which one was intended. We should be able to assume the *writer* is aware of multiple meanings (including, in context, nationwide chains of retailers who specialise in selling food/groceries). So if the meaning isn't clear, I'd place most of the blame on the writer anyway.

Comment: The second meaning is probably derived by analogy to *supply chain*, which I find slightly ironic as the people I would stereotype as obsessed with food sourcing are not exactly business school types.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, the original meaning, as the OED dating makes clear, was the one about a series of organisms, each succeeding one the predator of the former. 'The food chain' was used with the definite article. So it does seem altogether perverse that an entirely different process is described today as 'the food chain'. Personally I would avoid the second meaning, even though it is recognised by the OED.

Comment: @choster I think a good alternative expression, for the second meaning, might indeed be 'the food supply chain'.

Comment: @WS2: It's not obvious to me that OED's sense #2 is radically different to sense #1. It's significant that not only was the "original" 1920 citation placed in "scare quotes" (indicating the writer was perfectly well aware it was a somewhat "unusual" usage). When I check the full context, it's clear the reference specifically applies to *individual fish species which are eventually eaten by **humans***. If he'd been writing about some animal we *don't* normally eat (lions?, tigers?) perhaps he wouldn't have used the term at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The so-called 'scare quotes' are probably due to the fact that this was an early use of the term. But I well remember all the fuss over DDT and the way it passed down the food chain. That is totally different to talking about Tesco having full control over the 'food chain' from grower to consumer.

Comment: @WS2: Indeed. But arguably things have moved on, and "food chain" doesn't really cover all the "biological transfer/accumulation" issues environmental scientists are concerned with today. I'm not sure "organisms eating other organisms" is central to the problem of [fish being affected by exposure to oestrogen](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn11898-oestrogen-exposure-can-crash-fish-populations.html#.Utp8_tJFAgY), for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  But 'food chain' in its original sense may well be of considerable importance when looking at the effects of GM crops. We don't (yet) go as far as the Chinese in creating genetically modified pigs that grow as big as camels, but who knows what effect GM crops could have on pigs, chickens, turkeys, beef cattle, even milk production? (Tell the GM producers where they can stuff their seed. That's my motto.)

Comment: @WS2: Things have moved on a bit since credulous Victorians/Edwardians were keen to buy [radium-based toothpaste and the like](http://www.environmentalgraffiti.com/offbeat-news/10-radioactive-products-that-people-actually-used/1388). I think the biotechnicians are probably well on top of any *direct* threats to human health that might be caused by ingestion of GM products. (Not that we have much of it in Europe, unlike the US.) The risks are more about *environmental impact* (e.g. - on other species), which isn't really a "food chain" issue.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the second definition is a **metaphoric** subdivision of the first: the meaning of the chain is extended to include steps that aren't one organism eating another, but rather one group of people processing organic material to pass it on to another group, and to the next, etc.

As to how to distinguish between the two, I think **context** will usually make the intended meaning clear: if you're talking about processed food for humans, it will usually be the second definition; if it is about a wild animal, it will be the first definition.

Comment: It's not metaphoric, the first refers to a chain of actual food, one eating the other, and does have a common metaphoric use. The second refers to farms, factories, trucks, shops etc. which doesn't really fit any metaphorical view of the first.

Comment: @JonHanna: I can't prove it, and another explanation is possible. But the metaphorical view is that what happens in nature stands for what happens in our economy, so nature stands for human society. I certainly agree that, if this is/was a metaphor, it is not at least partly dead.

Comment: With respect to Jon Hannah, it almost fits the dictionary definition of 'metaphor', but the problem is that the two are close enough (both about food) as to be confusing. I am not sure that people using the second definition actually appreciate that they are speaking metaphorically. So it becomes a metaphor which threatens its parent figure. There may be others around like this and perhaps there should be a name for such things.

Comment: @WS2: Yeah, that's very common, dead metaphors eating their "parents"...oops, I used several metaphors at once there. It's just that metaphor is an extremely common, often trivial use we make of our language. P.S. See also *conceptual metaphor*.

Answer (score 1):

You left out **1b**, which is the figurative sense of **1a**, and very common.

I find utterly no confusion here though.

The two concepts both relate to a *chain* and both relate to *food* and do so understandably.

I could certainly create a deliberately awkward sentence such as:

> Such a negative impact on the food-chain could upset the food-chain.

But that's no different to many other pieces of bad English, and less likely than many.

I did not mis-interpret your question's title as referring to the average movement of the sun along the ecliptic, or as being about a lamentation, though those are both senses of *meaning*.

As words go, having a mere two senses, with little in the way of overlap, makes it pretty unambiguous in each.

Comment: Actually, your example is ambiguous in the sense that the meanings for each use of "food-chain" can be inverted ;)

Comment: @Jim, yes I was trying to be bad on purpose. My point is that while one **can** come up with cases where there's a problem, one generally will not.